# Convert array of array's each array into array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to convert an array of array's each array into a string.

I know the method flat where all the array of the array becomes a single array but this is not solving my full purpose.

```js
array = [['ba','ab'],['bab','abb']]
```

my tried code is:

```js
let merged = array.map(a => {
  console.log(a)
  a.reduce((a, b) => a.concat(b), []);
})

console.log(merged);
```

Expected output is: `[['ba,ab'],['bab, abb']]`

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: @UthistranSelvaraj i have given in the bottom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) for this purpose. From the documentation:

> The `join()` method creates and returns a new string by concatenating all of the elements in an array (or an array-like object), separated by commas or a specified separator string. If the array has only one item, then that item will be returned without using the separator.

Like the following:

```js
const array = [['ba', 'ab'], ['bab', 'abb']];
const result = array.map(e => e.join(','));
console.log(result);
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: i posted wrong output can you tell me how to get this output ?

Answer (score 1):

You could map the joined values.

```js
var array = [['ba', 'ab'], ['bab', 'abb']],
    result = array.map(a => a.join(', '));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

With respect to your comment on @norbitrial answer.
Plus a little JS type conversion hack (just for education, you'd better use `join(",")`). And I think you should accept his answer.

```js
const array = [['ba', 'ab'], ['bab', 'abb']];
const result = array.map(e => ["" + e]);
console.log(result);
```